# Thermodynamic cycle, finding a ratio from T2/T1

Tags: python, physics

I have to code to find a value of T2/T1 with efficiency of 30%. So how do i create the code to find T2/T1

[image: the equation]

```
γ = 5/3
x = T2/T1
r1 = np.log(x)
```

*ps would be great if done by bisection method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm done
γ = 5/3

```
def f(x):
    return (np.log(x)-(1-(1/x)))/(np.log(x)+(1-(1/x)/(γ-1)))-(3/10)

while True:
    a = float(input("Masukkan variabel nilai a:"))
    b = float(input("Masukkan variabel nilai b:"))

    if f(a)*f(b) > 0:
        print("Tidak ada akar antara variabel a & b")
        print("Masukan angka lain")
        
    else:
        break
    
nilai_toleransi = float(input("Masukkan nilai toleransi:"))

beda = abs(a-b)
while beda > nilai_toleransi:
    c = (a+b)/2
    if f(a)*f(c) > 0:
        a = c
    
    else:
        b = c
    beda = abs(a-b)

root = (a+b)/2
print(root)
```